# BaseX: How can one delete an XML file from disk?

Tags: xml, xquery, basex

I am trying to delete a file from hard disk using BaseX 7.9 GUI. First, I set WRITEBACK to true:

[image: BaseX Command. Setting WRITEBACK to true.]

I then make sure it has been correctly set using `db:system()`, having the following result:

```
<system>
    ...
    <writeback>true</writeback>
    ...
</system>
```

Finally, I perform `db:delete('db','test00001.xml')`, successfully removing the file from the database. However, when I go check on the file's actual directory I find the file is still there.

Is it possible to delete a file from hard disk with BaseX GUI. Is there something wrong with the way I am trying to delete the file? What would be the right way?

Comment: I don't think WIRTEBACK also triggers to delete a file. One could consider this an unexpected behaviour, you might want to raise the issue on our ML (https://mailman.uni-konstanz.de/mailman/listinfo/basex-talk). If you want to manually delete the file, you can use `file:delete()` (see http://docs.basex.org/wiki/File_Module#file:delete)

Comment: So WRITEBACK only propagates to hard disk  an **update** to the file? Another question: does `file:delete()` only delete the file from hard disk or does it also remove its reference from DB tables? Thank you.

Comment: all `file:` operations operate on the file system level and have nothing to do with existing databases